# Symfony 5.1 | config/services.php is not working

Tags: php, symfony

I am implementing the [interface autowiring](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#working-with-interfaces).

The config/services.yaml example works just fine but when using config/services.php instead of config/services.yaml the code in config/services.php does not get triggered.

So this works:

```yaml
# config/services.yaml
services:
    # ...

    App\Util\Rot13Transformer: ~

    # the ``App\Util\Rot13Transformer`` service will be injected when
    # an ``App\Util\TransformerInterface`` type-hint is detected
    App\Util\TransformerInterface: '@App\Util\Rot13Transformer'
```

But this does not:

```php
// config/services.php
namespace Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\Configurator;

use App\Util\Rot13Transformer;
use App\Util\TransformerInterface;

return function(ContainerConfigurator $configurator) {
    $services = $configurator->services();
    $services->set(Rot13Transformer::class);

    // the ``App\Util\Rot13Transformer`` service will be injected when
    // an ``App\Util\TransformerInterface`` type-hint is detected
    $services->alias(TransformerInterface::class, Rot13Transformer::class);
};
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

I also added invalid php code into config/services.php and no error is thrown. So this leads me to conclude that config/services.php is not being ran at all.

Comment: I have found that you always have to clear the cache (bin/console cache:clear) after changing services.php or routes.php.  Not sure if this is a feature or a bug.  And if you still think services.php is never being loaded, take a look at Kernel::configureContainer and make sure nothing funny is going on.  There have been some recent tweaks.

Comment: And of course you have to remove config/services.yaml because if it is present then it will be loaded in place of services.php.  At least in 5.1.3.

Comment: @Cerad I am doing the cache:clear. I am keeping the config/services.yaml though so that might be it. I checked the Kernel::configureContainer and you are right, it seems that it either loads yaml or php, not both. I am gonna try removing the yaml now.

Comment: @Cerad I deleted the services.yaml and added the default values ( see https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html#the-new-default-services-yaml-file ) into services.php + the interface alias and it worked like a charm. Thank you

Comment: @Cerad Please go ahead and re-post your comment ( remove yaml ) as an anwer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for a bit of context, starting in 5.1 Symfony has been moving towards using php based config/services.php and routes.php files for configuration in place of yaml files.

However, you need to remove the corresponding yaml file in order to allow the php files to be loaded.  You can see this in Kernel::configureContainer().

And in my setups at least, I also find that I have to manually run "bin/console clear:cache" after making changes to either services.php or routes.php.  The cache is not being automatically refreshed like it does with the yaml files.  Could just be something I am doing wrong.

The php based service and route builders are quite powerful.  They give you lots of syntax checking and autocompletion help. Well worth investigating.  The docs have side by side examples of yaml vs xml vs php.